# How to fix the current tab widget in Python tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create an application using Python tkinter. The problem occur after uploading an excel file with multiple sheets inside. The application did display the sequence of the sheets correctly. However, when I create a button to go to another page in each sheets, the button will direct me to different sheet.

It should be directed to another page with the same data of the current tab, which is if the current tab is Sheet 1, then the next page should also contain all data from Sheet 1.

However, my code did the other way:
For example, if I have 2 sheets in an excel file, named `Sheet 1` and `Sheet 2`.
When I `click` on the button in the `Sheet 1`, it will directed to another page with all information including variable and sheet name from `Sheet 2`.
**This is wrong!**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlrd
import tkinter as tk

from tkinter import Frame, Menu, Button, Label, Canvas, Entry, Toplevel, StringVar, OptionMenu
from tkinter import LEFT, RIGHT, TOP, BOTTOM, X, FLAT, RAISED
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def newPage():
    global currentVal

    newWin = Toplevel(root)
    newWin.title("newPage")
    width = 500
    height = 500
    screen_width = newWin.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = newWin.winfo_screenheight()
    x = (screen_width/2) - (width/2)
    y = (screen_height/2) - (height/2)
    newWin.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (width, height, x, y))
    newWin.resizable(0,0)

    #create ttk frame(Tab Widget)
    tabnewPageControl = ttk.Notebook(newWin)
    tabnewPage = ttk.Frame(tabnewPageControl)
    currentTab = sheetName[tabControl.index("current")-1] #Get current Tab

    lblFile = Label(tabnewPage, text = "Select a variable:")
    lblFile.grid(row = 1)

    currentCol = list()
    worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(currentTab)
    for y in range(worksheet.ncols):
        currentCol.append(worksheet.cell(0,y).value)

    #Option menu
    global currentVal

    currentVal = StringVar(root)
    currentVal.set(currentCol[0])
    popMenu = OptionMenu(tabnewPage, currentVal, *currentCol).grid(row = 1, column = 2)

    tabnewPageControl.add(tabnewPage, text = currentTab)
    tabnewPageControl.pack(expand = 1, fill = "both", side = LEFT)
    tabnewPageControl.focus()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Main Window")
width = 1000
height = 500
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
x = (screen_width/2) - (width/2)
y = (screen_height/2) - (height/2)
root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (width, height, x, y))
root.resizable(1,1)

def browseFile():
    global workbook, copyWorkbook, excel_file, sheetName, worksheet

    fileName = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select File", 
                                          filetypes=(("excel file",".xlsx"), ("excel file",".xls"), ("all files", "*.*")))
    excel_file = pd.ExcelFile(fileName)
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(fileName)
    sheetCount = workbook.nsheets

    #Looping Create tabs
    sheetName = []
    tab = []
    for x in range(workbook.nsheets):
        tab.append(ttk.Frame(tabControl))
        sheetName = workbook.sheet_names()
        tabControl.add(tab[x], text = sheetName[x])
        df_table = excel_file.parse(sheetName[x])
        lblTable = Label(tab[x],text = df_table.to_string(index = False)).grid()
        btnnewPage = Button (tab[x], text="newPage", command = newPage).grid(sticky = 'w', column = 0, row =5)

##TOOLBAR MENU
toolbar = Frame(root, bd = 1, relief = RAISED)

#To browse excel file
btnOpen = Button(toolbar, text = "Open", compound = TOP, relief = FLAT, activebackground = '#ADD8E6', padx = 10, pady = 1, command = browseFile).pack(side = LEFT)
btnQuit = Button(toolbar, text = "Quit", compound = TOP, relief = FLAT, activebackground = '#ADD8E6', padx = 10, pady = 1, command = root.quit).pack(side = RIGHT)
toolbar.pack(side = TOP, fill = X)

###Tab Widget
tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root)
tabHome = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tabControl.pack(expand = 1, fill = 'both', side = LEFT)

root.mainloop() #main method 2 - run the application
```

**I did not have any problem before I added the toolbar menu**.
Is there something wrong with how I define and create my toolbar menu?

Comment: Move this: `sheetName = workbook.sheet_names()` outside the `for x ` and loop from `for x in sheetName:`

Comment: Change to `currentTab = ....index("current")]`, `.index(...` is `0-based`.

Comment: I changed the index based and it work! Thanks @stovfl